Quartz C# don't execute Job
I have a problem with a basic implementation of quartz on a .net 4.7.2 project with quartz in 3.8.0, everything seems to work except Execute which is not even run.
The code is in place on a library project and executed on a wpf application (so it stay alive), the problem had already happened to me in the past and started to work again on its own without any explanation.
No error message, exception...
        {
            try
            {
                var factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
                var scheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();
                
                IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<SimpleJob>()
                    .WithIdentity("TestJob", "TestGroup")
                    .Build();

                ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                    .WithIdentity("TestTrigger", "TestGroup")
                    .StartNow()
                    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(5).RepeatForever())
                    .Build();

                await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
                
                await scheduler.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception : " + ex);
            }
        }
        public class SimpleJob : IJob
        {
            public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SimpleJob executed at: " + DateTime.Now);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        } ```



I found a solution to my problem, I implemented the quartz logs and an error which had not reached me appeared (only within the quartz logs) indicating a problem with the dll reference between my projects , after updating the references the sheduler started to work correctly.
